# How to verify array and add number if not certain number?

Tags: java, arrays

I think the title might make it sound easier than it is.

Basically I have to check if a 2d suduko array is valid.

```
public class Sudoku{

//The n x m grid that defines the Sudoku
private int[][] theGrid;
//the number that defines the empty cell
private int empty;

//constructor
public Sudoku(int[][] g){
    theGrid = g;
}

//secondary constructor, where e represents the empty cell
public Sudoku(int[][] g, int e){
    theGrid = g;
    empty = e;
}

public boolean isValid(){
//checks each row, column and sub box inside
}
```

The following function is called for every row, column and sub box, after putting the aforementioned into an array to make sure each aspect of the sudkou is valid.

```
public boolean checkValues(int[] a){
    int[] vals = new int[a.length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        //number out of range and not empty cell
        if ((a[i] < 1 || a[i] > a.length) && a[i]!=empty)
            return false;
        //duplicate number and not empty cell
        if (vals[a[i]] > 0 && a[i]!=empty)
            return false;
        //mark number as used  
        vals[a[i]]++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now heres the problem. If you create the sudoku grid using -1 or 10 (or any number outside of its range) as an empty cell, it returns an arrayindexoutofbounds exception. i am assuming `vals[a[i]]++` is the culprit as its trying to add a number that doesnt exists. So how do I fix it so it only adds the number if its not an empty cell? Ive tried

```
if(a[i]!=empty)
   vals[a[i]]++;
```

but it gives me the same error.

I originally had

```
//secondary constructor, where e represents the empty cell
public Sudoku(int[][] g, int e){
    for(int i = 0; i < g.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < g[0].length; j++){
            //for every instance of empty cell e, change to specific value
            if(g[i][j] == e){
                g[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    theGrid = g;
}
```

which would force every empty cell to be 0, and in the `checkValues` had `a[i]!=0` instead of `a[i]!=empty` but changed it because of one test where a sudoku was created using `-1` as an empty cell, but it actually had `0` in it. So it shouldve returned false, but was returning true.

Also, is there a way to make it so if created using the constructor with only 1 parameter `sudoku(int[][] g)`, itll return false if it has `0`, because it was not denoted to be an empty cell. Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: "If you create the sudoku grid using -1 or 10" Why do you think you want to do this? That is clearly not a valid sudoku!

Comment: @JoeC using -1 or 10 as an empty cell

Comment: Ah. May I suggest the [`OptionalInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html) class to you then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the `a[i]` is not empty first:

change

```
if (vals[a[i]] > 0 && a[i]!=empty)
    return false;
```

to

```
if (a[i]!=empty && vals[a[i]] > 0)
    return false;
```

This takes advantage of the `&&` (AND) operator being a short circuited operator - if the first (left) operand is `false`, the second (right) operand is not evaluated, so `vals[a[i]] > 0` will only be evaluated if `a[i]` contains a non empty value.

You also have to add a range check before incrementing the counter:

```
if (a[i]!=empty)
    vals[a[i]]++;
```

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. Man I had everything, just in a different order haha. Thanks for your help.